# How do I simplify $\arg(z-w)$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

When solving for the locus of this kind of expression I always get confused.

Is there any way of simplifying this into something that makes sense? For example something like this:

$$\arg(z-w) = \arg(z)-\arg(w)$$

Is this correct? Do you know of any ways to simplify this kind of expression?

For example, I have $\frac{\pi}{2}\le \arg(z+i) \le \frac{3\pi}{2}$. If I could simplify  $\arg(z+i)$ into something like $\arg(z)+\arg(i)$ I could find the locus more easily.

I think I've done an exercise in the past in which I did that, but I don't remember exactly.

So my question is, how do you simplify $\arg(z-w)$?

Comment: Drawing a picture and busting out the good old trig functions is the way to go.

Comment: @Arthur Give me a clue

Comment: That was my clue. I personally, wholeheartedly recommend you find a piece of paper and a pen, and draw everything. Then, with the drawings as a guideline, use trigonometry to find what you need.

Comment: for z|=0 ,arg z  is a set valued function  =  t  where is real and satisfies

Comment: There is not way you can get $arg(z - w)$ just with $arg(z)$ and $arg(w)$. For example, fix $w$ and take $r z$, for $r \in \Bbb R$.Then, on your picture you can see easily that the argument is changing. 
You are trying to find a close formula for $arg(re^{i\theta} + \rho e^{i \psi})$. As you can see, it surely depends on $r, \rho, \theta, \psi$ and the formula is probably not very nice/useful, to my humble opinion.

Comment: What is your definition of arg z ,it is a set valued function ,

Comment: @N.H. +1 Thank you, very enlightenint comment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any nice way to simplify $\arg(z-w)$. But as far as finding the locus of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}\le \arg(z+i) \le \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$, here's how I'd do it:

Think from the outside in; set $w = z+i$. we need to find all complex numbers which satisfy $\dfrac{\pi}{2}\le \arg(w) \le \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$. In other words, all complex numbers which have an angle between $\dfrac {\pi}{2}$ and $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$, inclusive. Well, that's all of quadrants II and III.

[image]

But each of these $w's$ in the blue shaded area are actually $z's$ shifted up by $1$ unit (adding $i$ to $z$ shifts $z$ up by one unit). So to get back each $z$, shift each $w$ down by $1$. From the picture it is clear that shifting the shaded area down by $1$ will not change anything, because the shaded area is infinite up, down, and to the left.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Comment: @MarkRead You're welcome!

Comment: By the way, how would you solve this if $w = z/i$ instead?

Comment: @MarkRead In that case you could rewrite it as $z = iw$. When you multiply $2$ complex numbers, you multiply their lengths and add their angles. The length of $i$ is $1$ and it's angle is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. So to get from $w$ to $z$, you would take $w$ and add $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ to its angle. So basically each $q$ will be rotated counterclockwise by $90$ degrees, therefore the whole shaded area will be rotated by $90$ degrees, and the final picture will be quadrants $3$ and $4$ shaded.

Comment: Right, I understand. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRead No problem.